# Why does Ruby 2.3.0 JSON.parse give unexpected token error?

Tags: ruby, json

I have the following JSON returned in a response:

```
"{\n  \"notices\": [\n    {\n      \"id\": \"1234\",\n      \"projectId\": 1,\n      \"groupId\": \"55\",\n      \"createdAt\": \"2014-10-22T03:00:00.407Z\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"id\": \"1234\",\n      \"projectId\": 1,\n      \"groupId\": \"55\",\n      \"createdAt\": \"2014-10-22T03:00:00.407Z\"\n    },\n  ],\n  \"count\": 2\n}\n"
```

In irb for Ruby 2.3.0, when I use `JSON.parse(x)` on the above response, I get:

```
JSON::ParserError: 419: unexpected token at '],
  "count": 2
}'
```

even though http://jsonlint.com says it is valid JSON.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting. The YAML parser, which can also parse JSON, accepts the string without complaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with having a comma after the last object in your array:

```
\"createdAt\": \"2014-10-22T03:00:00.407Z\"\n    },\n  ],\n  \"count\": 2\n}\n"
                                                  ^ This comma
```

After getting rid of it, I got the parse to work as expected:

```
JSON.parse("{\n  \"notices\": [\n    {\n      \"id\": \"1234\",\n      \"projectId\": 1,\n      \"groupId\": \"55\",\n      \"createdAt\": \"2014-10-22T03:00:00.407Z\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"id\": \"1234\",\n      \"projectId\": 1,\n      \"groupId\": \"55\",\n      \"createdAt\": \"2014-10-22T03:00:00.407Z\"\n    }  ],\n  \"count\": 2\n}\n")
=> {"notices"=>[{"id"=>"1234", "projectId"=>1, "groupId"=>"55", "createdAt"=>"2014-10-22T03:00:00.407Z"}, {"id"=>"1234", "projectId"=>1, "groupId"=>"55", "createdAt"=>"2014-10-22T03:00:00.407Z"}], "count"=>2}
```

Comment: oh, my bad, you point to the object, but I point to the comma :)